# When does Word2Vec#fit() terminate and why is my alpha not getting smaller?

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I am trying to train word vectors from a large dataset (approx. 50GB) on our cluster but I am not sure if the training is going to terminate.

The logs reveal that `alpha` is actually *not* getting smaller as I think it should:

```
...
16/04/13 17:19:01 INFO feature.Word2Vec: wordCount = 17974000, alpha = 0.5506481187235711
16/04/13 17:19:02 INFO feature.Word2Vec: wordCount = 17985000, alpha = 0.5506791151242587
16/04/13 17:19:02 INFO feature.Word2Vec: wordCount = 17996000, alpha = 0.5507101115249463
16/04/13 17:19:03 INFO feature.Word2Vec: wordCount = 18007000, alpha = 0.550741107925634
16/04/13 17:19:04 INFO feature.Word2Vec: wordCount = 18018000, alpha = 0.5507721043263216
16/04/13 17:19:05 INFO feature.Word2Vec: wordCount = 18029000, alpha = 0.5508031007270092
```

Below is the part of the `Word2Vec#fit()` function that would update `alpha`. You can see that the lower bound for `alpha` is `learningRate * 0.0001`.

```scala
alpha = learningRate * 
        (1 - numPartitions * wordCount.toDouble / (trainWordsCount + 1))

if (alpha < learningRate * 0.0001) {
    alpha = learningRate * 0.0001
}

logInfo("wordCount = " + wordCount + ", alpha = " + alpha)
```

The `learningRate` (here `0.5`) appears to be constant as well as well as `numPartitions` (here `1`). `trainWordsCount` is as far as I can tell the vocabulary size and also appears to be constant. The only thing that is changing is `wordCount` which is growing over time.

This means if

```
numPartitions * wordCount.toDouble >= trainWordsCount + 1
```

then `alpha` would start to become bigger.
I am not sure if this is actually a problem but I red somewhere that it should actually become smaller. At the moment I am also not sure if this is a bug, if this is actually okay or if I am doing something wrong.

Can somebody explain to me what I could/should expect from this function? 
Please let me know if you need further information.

---

I can provide the entire code if needed but this is the essential part:

```
val outputDirectoryPath = new Path(args(1))
var wordsToKeepCount = args(2).toInt
val learningRate = args(3).toDouble
val numW2vPartitions = args(4).toInt

// ..

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

// ..

var minCount = 50
val vectorSize = 500
val windowSize = 10
var wordSequence : RDD[Seq[String]] = null

// ..

val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
val model = word2vec
  .setMinCount(minCount.asInstanceOf[Int])
  .setVectorSize(vectorSize)
  .setWindowSize(windowSize)
  .setNumPartitions(numW2vPartitions)
  .setLearningRate(learningRate)
  .fit(wordSequence)
```

Comment: What's your learning rate ?

Comment: @eliasah `0.5`  in this example (always smaller than `1.0`) but I just stumbled of the following: `Word2Vec: trainWordsCount = -2129279483` so it seems that Word2Vec might experience an integer overflow which could explain what I observe ..

Comment: Try with different learning rates then, maybe it's stuck in a local minima

Comment: @eliasah Well I increased the min word count to 5000.. now `trainWordsCount = 2036212495` .. I actually don't know what that means. I have 10 partitions where each has now approx. `wordCount = 377,860,700`  and the `alpha` is at it's lower bound.. Since I have 10 partitions I'd have 3,778,607,000 words by now .. so why is it not terminated yet? Another thing I don't get is.. the `minWordCount`.. it makes sense to set it but why can I not set something like `maxTotalWordCount` or something to limit the number of words in my final dictionary..

Comment: Try to precompute the N (e.g. N=500000) most frequent words of your training corpus (probably excluding stop-words) and remove all words not included in this set from the RDD before calling `Word2Vec.fit(...)` on it.